# C# select duplicate using group

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I would like to select only from non-blank Names where any Group contains same ID multiple times:

**Data Setup**

```
var a1 = new { id = 3, Name = "", Group = "GroupA" };
var a2 = new { id = 2, Name = "", Group = "GroupA" };
var a3 = new { id = 3, Name = "", Group = "GroupA" };
var b1 = new { id = 4, Name = "B", Group = "GroupB" };
var b2 = new { id = 5, Name = "B", Group = "GroupB" };
var b3 = new { id = 5, Name = "B", Group = "GroupB" };
List<dynamic> group = new List<dynamic>();
group.Add(a1);
group.Add(a2);
group.Add(a3);
group.Add(b1);
group.Add(b2);
group.Add(b3);
```

**Query:**

```
var query1 = group.ToList()
    .Where(s=>s.Name != "")
    .GroupBy(x =>x.Group)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(y => y)
    .ToList();
Console.WriteLine("output\n" + string.Join("\n", query1));
```

Returns

```
 id = 4, Name = B, Group = GroupB 
 id = 5, Name = B, Group = GroupB 
 id = 5, Name = B, Group = GroupB
```

But what I wanted is the following:

```
 id = 5, Name = B, Group = GroupB 
 id = 5, Name = B, Group = GroupB
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What should happen with items that have the same `id` but a different `Group`? Eg. `new {id=1,Group="A"}` and `new {id=1,Group="B"}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by `id` and/or `Name` depending on your needs

```
.GroupBy(x => new {x.id, x.Name})
```

**Given**

```
var list = new[]
{
   new {id = 3, Name = "", Group = "GroupA"},
   new {id = 2, Name = "", Group = "GroupA"},
   new {id = 3, Name = "", Group = "GroupA"},
   new {id = 4, Name = "B", Group = "GroupB"},
   new {id = 5, Name = "B", Group = "GroupB"},
   new {id = 5, Name = "B", Group = "GroupB"}
};
```

**Usage**

```
var results = list
   .Where(s => s.Name != "")
   .GroupBy(x => new {x.id, x.Name})
// .GroupBy(x => x.id) <- depending on your needs
   .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
   .SelectMany(y => y);

foreach (var result in results)
   Console.WriteLine($"{result.id}, {result.Name}, {result.Group}");
```

**Output**

```
5, B, GroupB
5, B, GroupB
```

Comment: Thanks now what if I change names to A B C, how do i get the same result?

Answer (score 1):

You are applying `GroupBy` to `Group` property. Instead of Grouping by `Group` property, use `id` property,

**Input**

```
var list = new[]
{
    new {id = 3, Name = "", Group = "GroupA"},
    new {id = 2, Name = "", Group = "GroupA"},
    new {id = 3, Name = "", Group = "GroupA"},
    new {id = 4, Name = "B", Group = "GroupB"},
    new {id = 5, Name = "B", Group = "GroupB"},
    new {id = 5, Name = "B", Group = "GroupB"}
};
```

**Solution:**

```
var query1 = list.ToList()
    .Where(s=>s.Name != "")
    .GroupBy(x =>x.id)  
               //^^^^^ This change you need to do  
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(y => y)
    .ToList();
```

**Output**

```
5, B, GroupB
5, B, GroupB
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JjR9vC)