# C# select duplicates from sub-group

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I would like to filter out "" names then select each unique location where there are duplicate IDs regardless of name:

**Data Setup**

```cs
var list = new[]
{
    new { id = 3, Name = "", Location = "LocationA" },
    new { id = 2, Name = "", Location = "LocationA" },
    new { id = 1, Name = "T", Location = "LocationB" },
    new { id = 2, Name = "H", Location = "LocationB" },
    new { id = 3, Name = "E", Location = "LocationB" },
    new { id = 3, Name = "R", Location = "LocationB" },
    new { id = 5, Name = "U", Location = "LocationC" },
    new { id = 5, Name = "S", Location = "LocationC" },
    new { id = 5, Name = "S", Location = "LocationD" },
    new { id = 4, Name = "O", Location = "LocationD" },
    new { id = 4, Name = "Z", Location = "LocationE" },
};
```

**Query**

```cs
var query1 = list
    .Where(s => s.Name != "")
    .GroupBy(g => g.Location)
    .Where(w => w.Select(s => s.Location).Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(s => s)
    .GroupBy(g => g.id)
    .Where(w => w.Select(s => s.id).Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(s => s)
    .ToList();
Console.WriteLine("output\n" + string.Join("\n", query1));
```

**Returns**

```
{ id = 3, Name = E, Location = LocationB }
{ id = 3, Name = R, Location = LocationB }
{ id = 5, Name = U, Location = LocationC }
{ id = 5, Name = S, Location = LocationC }
{ id = 5, Name = S, Location = LocationD }
```

***vs* What I actually wanted**

```
{ id = 3, Name = E, Location = LocationB }
{ id = 3, Name = R, Location = LocationB }
{ id = 5, Name = U, Location = LocationC }
{ id = 5, Name = S, Location = LocationC }
```

LocationD has IDs 4 & 5 so it should've been filtered out, I wasn't able to do so.  What am I doing wrong?  How do I correct it?

Comment: I guess you are asking similar question again, https://stackoverflow.com/q/69733137/6299857

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# select duplicate using group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69733137/c-sharp-select-duplicate-using-group)

Comment: No it's not, if you run solution from that inquiry using input from this inquiry you'll get 7 returns vs actual answer of 4.  Inquiry here is different, I am looking do multiple groupings or group first then regroup again vs previous inquiry on single group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by `id` and `Location`. And get `.Count()` more than 1.

```cs
var query1 = list
    .Where(s => s.Name != "")
    .GroupBy(g => new { g.Location, g.id })
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .ToList();
```

[Sample demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gU0eSN)

Answer (score 2):

**Given**

```
var list = new[]
{
   new { id = 3, Name = "", Location = "LocationA" },
   new { id = 2, Name = "", Location = "LocationA" },
   new { id = 1, Name = "T", Location = "LocationB" },
   new { id = 2, Name = "H", Location = "LocationB" },
   new { id = 3, Name = "E", Location = "LocationB" },
   new { id = 3, Name = "R", Location = "LocationB" },
   new { id = 5, Name = "U", Location = "LocationC" },
   new { id = 5, Name = "S", Location = "LocationC" },
   new { id = 5, Name = "S", Location = "LocationD" },
   new { id = 4, Name = "O", Location = "LocationD" },
   new { id = 4, Name = "Z", Location = "LocationE" },
};
```

**Example**

```
var results = list
   .Where(s => s.Name != "")
   .GroupBy(x => new {x.id, x.Location})
   .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
   .SelectMany(y => y);

foreach (var result in results)
   Console.WriteLine($"{result.id}, {result.Name}, {result.Location}");
```

**Output**

```
3, E, LocationB
3, R, LocationB
5, U, LocationC
5, S, LocationC
```

Comment: Hi TheGeneral, you already answered to the same question asked by same OP yesterday. I don't know why OP is asking similar question instead of reading and putting some efforts by him/her self

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar ahh yup. The ops current attempt was definitely  over baked

Comment: Thanks for helps Gen, I tried previous solution at work yesterday then realized it was not what I was looking for so I refined my inquiry again.  Your solution is perfect here, will do the trick